# Est-ce que je peux utiliser le gérondif dans une mise en relief?

Tags: grammaire, participe-présent, emphase

Est-ce que je peux utiliser le gérondif dans une mise en relief?

Par exemple :

> Ce n'est pas en te sentant coupable que tu pourras te soulager.

La forme que j'ai utilisée est *ce n'est pas* + gérondif + *que*

La forme standard serait

> Tu ne pourras pas te soulager en te sentant coupable.

Comment: Il est difficile comprendre ce que tu veux dire, peux tu écrire ton phrase dans une autre langue comme anglais pour que on puisse comprendre bien.

Comment: je voudrrais dir `tu ne pourras pas te soulager en te sentant coupable` mais je voudrais stresser sur en te sentant coupable

Comment: Les deux formes sont parfaitement correctes, et effectivement, la première permet d'attirer plus l'attention sur "en te sentant coupable"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ta formulation (*Ce n'est pas en te sentant coupable que tu pourras te soulager.*) est bonne. C'est juste et d'après ta description en commentaires cela correspond en effet très bien à l'idée que tu veux exprimer.

Pour se convaincre que cette forme est correcte, on a par exemple le proverbe archi-courant *C'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron.*

(ou bien la version de Desproges, pour certains bien meilleure, *C'est en lisant qu'on devient liseron.*)

Comment: Merci de votre suivi

Answer (score 1):

**Ce n'est pas te sentir coupable qui vas te soulager**.

Le *en te sentant coupable* est un peu trop soutenue, pour se glisser dans une tournure relâchée « *C'est pas … que* » .

Par ailleurs, le *tu pourras te soulager* est à éviter à tout prix. Cela veux dire *aller aux toilettes*.

Comment: Je ne vois absolument pas ce que tu as à reprocher à la phrase proposée en exemple, elle me semble bien plus naturelle que celle que tu proposes. Au passage, je te soulage d'un vote que j'estime injustifié… au risque de te faire c. :-)

Comment: Je ne sais pas ce que je lui reproche, mais elle me fait tiquer. *Ce n'est pas en continuant à te sentir coupable que tu vas être soulagé.* ?